# How to merge the list of records based on common field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: CONT ID EFFECTIVE_DATE M_ID HOME_PHONE_NO WORK_PHONE_NO PREFERED_CONTACT_NO 1 1 10/12/1995 12101 789456123 NULL NULL 1 1 10/12/1995 12101 NULL NULL 6879455035 1 1 10/12/1995 12101 NULL 6879455035 NULL]

I'm expecting a result like this.

[image]

I try this query

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CONT), ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, M_ID,
    MAX(HOME_PHONE_NO) AS HOME_PHONE_NO, 
    MAX(WORK_PHONE_NO) AS WORK_PHONE_NO,  
    MAX(PREFERED_CONTACT_NO) AS PREFERED_CONTACT_NO 
FROM  
    Wrk_INSERT1
GROUP BY 
    ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, M_ID, HOME_PHONE_NO, WORK_PHONE_NO
```

It is not working as expected. I am getting result like below

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Also try reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and editing your question, which will help us answer you.

Comment: not working as expected as in it result the first picture or did you get errors related to columns not in `group by`?

Comment: I received all of the records, which were not merged. @BagusTesa

Comment: @Aarlaneth I apologise about the image upload. I have no idea how to change the table data. the reason I uploaded the image

Answer (score 0):

Handle the null by "isnull" then output will come according to your expectation :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CONT) AS CONT, ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, M_ID,
    MAX(ISNULL(HOME_PHONE_NO, '')) AS HOME_PHONE_NO, 
    MAX(ISNULL(WORK_PHONE_NO)) AS WORK_PHONE_NO,  
    MAX(ISNULL(CELL_PHONE_NO, '')) AS CELL_PHONE_NO, 
    MAX(ISNULL(FAX_NO, '')) AS FAX_NO, 
    MAX(ISNULL(EMAIL_ADDRESS, '')) AS EMAIL_ADDRESS,  
    MAX(ISNULL(PREFERED_CONTACT_NO, '')) AS PREFERED_CONTACT_NO,
    MAX(ISNULL(EXTN, '')) AS EXTN,
    MAX(ISNULL(HME_PHN_EXTN, '')) AS HME_PHN_EXTN, 
    MAX(ISNULL(WRK_PHN_EXTN, '')) AS WRK_PHN_EXTN, 
    MAX(ISNULL(CEL_PHN_EXTN, '')) AS CEL_PHN_EXTN  
FROM  
    Wrk_CONV_SYNCUP_INS_UPD_PERSON_CONTACT_MTE_INSERT1
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. it is extremely helpful to me.